# How can I add some text to the end of a string of an array?

Tags: php

The following array contains several languages and another string named "Music". I want to add the text " News" right behind every language that is inside `cat_name`.

In the end the text should become "German News" etc., but "Music" should not become "Music News".

How can I add the text " News" for objects that were checked to contain "German", "Japanese", or "Chinese" in it's `cat_name`?

The key number is unknown.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3051 (17) {
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(11) "German"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#3068 (17) {
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(4) "Chinese"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3068 (17) {
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(15) "Japanese"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#3068 (19) {
    ["cat_name"]=>
    &string(15) "Music"
  }
}
```

This is the code I tried (without success):

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$cat){
if (in_array($cat->cat_name, array('German', 'Japanese', 'Chinese'))){ $array['cat_name'] .= ' News';}}
```

Comment: To be honest, I searched for it, but I did not have any clue

Comment: just use a foreach, either reference each object copy and make the change or use the key in conjuction with an if statement.

Comment: maybe this code. `$array['cat_name'] .= ' News';` should be `$array[$key]->cat_name .= ' News';`. CMIWW

Comment: Finally!! I'm so sorry, but it took me too much effort during my research. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for loop` with an `if` statement specifically to exclude `Music`:

```
$array = array(
         array('cat_name' => 'English'), 
         array('cat_name' => 'Music')
         );

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i]['cat_name'] != 'Music')
    $array[$i]['cat_name'] .= ' News';
}

print_r($array);
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => English News
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cat_name] => Music
        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array(
         array('cat_name' => 'English'), 
         array('cat_name' => 'Music')
         );

$i=0;
foreach ($array as $key=>$cat){
    if($cat['cat_name'] !='Music'){
        $arrayy[$i]['cat_name'] = $cat['cat_name'].' News';
    } else {
        $arrayy[$i]['cat_name'] = $cat['cat_name'];
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($arrayy);
```